how to get total and used memmory using special files in filesystem in linux?
How to use /sys/fs to get total memmory free and used size?
I know total memory of the process
cat /proc/$pid/smaps | grep -i pss |  awk '{Total+=$2} END {print Total/1024/1024" GB"}'

the file  /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.stat contains a lot of information

Is there any reason to avoid commands like free and vmstat?

I believe the info you ask about can be found in /proc/meminfo.

Same trick as usual: you run strace program to see how it interacts with the operating system.
In this case, strace free will tell you it reads /proc/meminfo.
So that's the pseudo-file you need to read totals, which is what your question asks about. Nothing in /sys/fs!

the file /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.stat contains a lot of information

So does man cgroups, when you look for the memory controller there; at it's end it refers to Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.rst, which you can find online easily; the section on "Memory Interface Files" explains what each of these memory controller entries means.
